# Audio Switching without promp

Tags: audio, chromebook

My Chromebook has been sporadically switching audio from headphone to internal speaker, going back and forth nonstop without headphones.  Is there a setting I need to adjust or possibly a reset?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of the application that creates the problem. For example, if the problem happens within "Discord" then go to settings and change the audio output from **Default** to either your speakers or the headset.